# FBML tag to detect user language in a tab

Tags: facebook, fbml

I have a custom tab for a fan page that need to display a JPEG image. I have an image in English and one in French. Is there a way to detect the user locale in FBML to display the right image?

I know how to do this server side using the Facebook `fb_sig_locale` param but I was planning on just using the Static FBML app which is much simpler than setting up a whole custom application.

Answer (score 2):

You can put constraint by country, for that use this:

```
<fb:restricted-to location="us">
  <img src="../us_image.gif"/>
<fb:else>
  <img src="../world_image.gif"/>
</fb:else>
</fb:restricted-to>
```

check here for more constraints possible in fb:restricted-to :

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:restricted-to

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about that tag. But it still doesn't solve my problem since my main audience is French and English Canada. Quebec should be a country, it would make programming much simpler ;-)